# How do you start a React Native npm library?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have some code that I've written in a RN app, and I want to open-source and post it on npm for others to consume. What's the best workflow for writing a pure JS React Native library? Thanks!

Comment: Is it completely JavaScript?  Or does it have native extensions?

Comment: If it only javascript, then it is no different than any npm package: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages

Comment: It's completely JS, but it depends on the `react-native` library, and makes use of Flowtypes that the RN packager provides

Comment: no worries, build a distribution file of your lib, and simply publish to npm

Answer (score 2):

So these are the steps on how to create a re-usable React Native library and publish it to NPM:

1. Create an account at https://npmjs.com
2. Open command line terminal, type:
   `npx create-react-native-library your-library-name-here`
3. `cd your-library-name-here`
4. `npm login`
5. `npm install --save react-native-builder-bob`
6. `npm install`
7. `npx react-native-builder-bob build`
8. `npm publish`

You can verify at your https://npmjs.com home page that this library is now there. Now, to test it you have to create another React Native application, which will depend on the newly created library:

1. Open terminal
2. `npx react-native init MyTestApp`
3. `cd MyTestApp`
4. `npx install --save your-library-name-here`
5. Modify `App.js` main code entrypoint and make a call to a method in your library that multiplies two numbers to prove that the library works.
6. Open another terminal, go to project root folder and type:
   `npx react-native start`.
7. From the main terminal at step#1, type:
   `npx react-native run-android`

These steps needs a properly installed **Android Studio IDE** and **node** (Nodejs). The step to create the react-native library already has one callable pre-made test method called `multiply(a, b)`.

Answer (score 1):

If your module is pure JS, you can simply follow these steps to publish to npm:
https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages

Essentially, you are exporting a component from your main file (`index.js`). This should all be defined in your `package.json`
A RN example: https://github.com/ugiacoman/react-native-calendar
I'll be publishing this package to npm soon :)

If your module requires native code, you can use this generator to setup your project:
https://github.com/frostney/react-native-create-library